# Not getting the box on detected car

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, classification

I'm trying to run a python code to detect a car in an image and draw a box around it. But somehow, I'm not getting the box even though there is no error. The code I'm using is below:

The function to draw the box

```
def draw_boxes(img, bboxes, color=(0, 0, 255), thick=6):
    # Make a copy of the image
    imcopy = np.copy(img)
    # Iterate through the bounding boxes
    for bbox in bboxes:
        # Draw a rectangle given bbox coordinates
        cv2.rectangle(imcopy, bbox[0], bbox[1], color, thick)
    # Return the image copy with boxes drawn
    return imcopy
```

The function to draw the box

```
def search_windows(img, windows, model):
    #1) Create an empty list to receive positive detection windows
    #2) Iterate over all windows in the list
    test_images = []
    for window in windows:
        #3) Extract the test window from original image
        test_img = cv2.resize(img[window[0][1]:window[1][1], window[0][0]:window[1][0]], (64, 64))
        # Normalize image
        test_img = test_img/255
        # Predict and round the result
        test_images.append(test_img)
    test_images = np.array(test_images)

    prediction = np.around(model.predict(test_images))
    on_windows = [windows[i] for i in np.where(prediction==1)[0]]
    return on_windows
```

Read an image and use the functions to draw the box

```
img = mpimg.imread(test_images[0])

detected_windows = search_windows(img, windows, model)                       

window_img = draw_boxes(img, detected_windows, color=(0, 255, 0), thick=3)                    

plt.imshow(window_img)
```

Thanks in adanvce.

Comment: May be the car isn't detected, You may verify it by `print prediction`

Comment: The limit I set on my `prediction` is very high. I need to set the condition for `prediction` to somewhere around `0.4` or `0.5` and then work with it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I need to set a better limit for my `prediction` in the code. If I set `0.4` or `0.5` as the value, then I get the boxes and then work my way for better predictions.